# Sign Document with own RSA parameters which are Hex-encoded

Tags: c#, encoding, rsa, digital-signature, private-key

I wanna ask question about RSA sign on C#.

I have one document for sign. I have plain hex values of modulus, private exponent and public exponent. I dont' t want to signing with random generated keys. When I try with sign with sign tool, i have got result perfectly. But i can' t do it with C#. I am new for this kind of problem. So i am really stucked.

I looked a lot of sites and arcticles but i couldn't find any solution. Maybe there is but i can' t get it, i don' t know.

If you could explain to me with details(step-step), i will really be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you need the full set of CRT parameters for the private key, so if you have D you'll also need P, Q, DP, DQ, and InverseQ.

```
RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters();
rsaParams.Modulus = ParseHex(modulus);
rsaParams.Exponent = ParseHex(exponent);
rsaParams.D = ParseHex(d, rsaParams.Modulus.Length);
rsaParams.P = ParseHex(p, (rsaParams.Modulus.Length + 1) / 2);
rsaParams.Q = ParseHex(q, rsaParams.P.Length);
rsaParams.DP = ParseHex(dp, rsaParams.P.Length);
rsaParams.DQ = ParseHex(dq, rsaParams.P.Length);
rsaParams.InverseQ = ParseHex(inverseQ, rsaParams.P.Length);

RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
```

Where `ParseHex(string str, int len=-1)` is a routine which parses your hex strings to a fixed length array (if the hex string is short, the array should be left-padded with 0-byte values).